# Deploy Spring Cloud App into docker cluster using swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud

I know the question sounds quiet vague but I'll try to explain my problem statement.

I have a Spring cloud app (using Netflix Eureka as service discovery) with multiple services and they are deployed in docker containers, the containers are linked and spinned using docker compose, everything works fine with a single container deployment but the problem is to automate the scaling of individual services/containers i.e. to have multiple containers of a single service, since my containers are bonded with ports so docker-compose scale will not work.

I've googled and found that I can use a load balancer and and spin containers with different ports for a service, but I don't want that because of fact I'm using client side load balancing.

Can someone please suggest how can I automate spinning of multiple containers for a service keeping in mind that containers can communicate with each other using their service name.

Comment: If you are using Eureka why does it matter what port, or even host, the container is using?  It will register with Eureka and under the same service name and  then other services can use Eureka to discover all the addresses for that service.

Comment: @RyanBaxter, you are correct we can do that, but I was looking for a way to achieve this using docker-compose and swarm

Comment: I know if you link containers together the host name of the linked containers will be put in the hosts file, but this is not the sam was service discovery provided by eureka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question may be this can help someone.

Since I''m using Spring Cloud hence services registers themselves with Eureka by providing a service name so it doesn't make sense to bind public ports to containers, I've used below docker-compose file to achieve scaling, however there may be better ways to do so but for now it works for me.

```
version: '2'
services:
 eureka:
  image: eureka
  container_name: eureka
  ports: 
  - "8761:8761"

zuul:
image: zuul
container_name: zuul
ports:
  - "8080"
depends_on:
  - eureka

webapp:
image: web-app
ports:
  - "6001"
depends_on:
  - eureka

writer:
image: writer
ports:
  - "7001"
depends_on:
  - eureka

recorder:
image: recorder
ports:
  - "9001"
depends_on:
  - eureka
  - mongodb

mongodb:
image: mongo:latest
command: mongod --noprealloc --smallfiles --dbpath /data/db --nojournal --oplogSize 16 --noauth
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
environment:
  TERM: xterm
volumes:
  - /home/user/data/mongo:/data/db
```

PS: The yaml is not formatted above.

Comment: Hi @Apollo with this change can you route to web-app from zuul, using say http://web-app:6001  ?

Comment: @Tatha, above configuration is to link docker containers and to support spinning of multiple containers on same machine, for routing configuration please refer https://github.com/akhil6095/Spring-cloud-app